# diplay all items on click with different scenario with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where two sections have different scenario, in first case I have three listing items with first display by default and show all on view click, this one I was able to do, but in second scenario, I have the same section where by default two list items will appear and another view all will display all the listing items.

I wanted to handle this logically from one piece of JS code logically, but not able to, Hoping somebody can suggest

**EDIT:**

1. Section first will display 2 items initially and on view all click it will load all
2. Section second will display 3 items initially and on view all click will load all.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var numOfitem = $(".block__item").length;
var xItem = 2;
$('.block__item:lt('+xItem+')').css('display','block');
$(".view-all > a").click(function(){
 var xItem = (xItem+3 <= numOfitem) ? xItem+3 : numOfitem;
  $('.block__item:lt('+xItem+')').css('display','block');
  $(this).hide();
});
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.block__item{padding:5px 0 5px 0; margin-bottom:5px; background:#ffffff; width:300px; display:block; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; display:none;}
.view-all{margin:10px 0 40px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Section One Begin -->
<span>total items (2)</span>
<div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-all">
   <a href="javascript:;">View All</a>
 </div>

<!-- Section two begin -->
<span>total items (3)</span>
<div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-all">
   <a href="javascript:;">View All</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi sanjeev do you want to show all the data of selected section on click of view all?

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML?

Comment: @KiranShahi Yes, I want to show all data on click of view all, but on each section seperately

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/). [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) gets all preceding siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

Here is an example:

```js
var xItem = 2;
$('.view-all').each(function(){
  $(this).prevUntil('span','.block__item:lt(' + xItem + ')').css('display', 'block');
  var numOfitem = $('.view-all').prevUntil("span", '.block__item').length;
  xItem = (xItem + 3 <= numOfitem) ? xItem + 3 : numOfitem;
});

$(".view-all > a").click(function() {    $(this).parent().prevUntil('span','.block__item').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.block__item{padding:5px 0 5px 0; margin-bottom:5px; background:#ffffff; width:300px; display:block; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; display:none;}
.view-all{margin:10px 0 40px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Section One Begin -->
<span>total items (2)</span>
<div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-all">
   <a href="javascript:;">View All</a>
 </div>

<!-- Section two begin -->
<span>total items (3)</span>
<div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="block__item">
     <div class="bock__item-content">
       This is data
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-all">
   <a href="javascript:;">View All</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually the scenario is in first section, min 2 will display and on click all, it would display all, but in second scenario, min 3 will display and on click it will display all..

Comment: @SanjeevKumar is your elements static or dynamic (from ajax call)?